# Dynamically updating div styles when input changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I recently started learning vue.js and I was faced with the following task: there is some text that needs to be surrounded by a red frame, and the size of this red frame can be changed manually. BUT when changing the font size or the text itself, the frame itself must be recalculated, and it must frame the text. I calculate the dimensions of the frame using formulas, and they suit me quite well. The question is this: I added @change event handlers to the font and text fields, which call the block size recalculation function, but @change fires only when I write all the text and click the mouse somewhere outside the input field. The written code is given below

```
<template>
    <h2>contentText</h2>
    <input type="text" @change="recalculationDivSize" v-model="contentText">
    <h2>fontSize</h2>
    <input type="text" @change="recalculationDivSize" v-model="fontSize">
    <h2>width</h2>
    <input type="text" v-model="width">
    <h2>height</h2>
    <input type="text" v-model="height">

    <div class="label-text-area selected-this"
         :style="getElementStyle()">
        {{ contentText }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            width: 40,
            height: 30,
            fontSize: 20,
            contentText: "text",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSizeForFontWeight: function (text, fontWeight) {
            return {
                height: Math.floor(fontWeight * 2),
                width: Math.floor(fontWeight * 0.6) * (text.length + 1),
            }
        },
        recalculationDivSize: function () {
            var size = this.getSizeForFontWeight(this.contentText, this.fontSize);
            this.height = size.height;
            this.width = size.width;
        },

        getElementStyle: function () {
            return {
                height: this.height + 'px',
                width: this.width + 'px',
                fontSize: this.fontSize + 'px',
            }

        }
    }

}
</script>

<style>
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.selected-this {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.label-text-area {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
```

I would like the block sizes to be recalculated for each letter of text or font size number entered. That is, I entered one letter, recalculated the sizes, entered another recalculation of the sizes, removed another, another recalculation, and so on. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use @input for your usecase instead of @change,

> The change event is fired for input, select, and textarea elements when the user modifies the element's value. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

you can read further on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event